# Having an SSO error trying to get the token from a third party system

Tags: single-sign-on

I am receiving the following error in our sandbox instance, but not production. I have validated that the setups are the same. What could cause this error:

The remote server returned an error:

> (400) Bad Request. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at
>   Utility.HttpPost(String URI, String
>   strParameters)System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set
>   to an instance of an object. at Utility.GetAccessToken() at
>   Utility.GetUserByUserID(String strSalesForceID) at
>   acs.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)SSO failed! Error 2